# Convert an object to a new class

Tags: python, object

I have two very similar classes. ExampleWithASurprise inherits from Example, having one more attribute. my_examples stores all the examples between their creation and the moment I convert them to a dict.

```
my_examples = []


class Example:
    def __init__(self, stuff, morestuff):
        my_examples.append(self)
        self.stuff = stuff
        self.stiff = 10 + morestuff

    def to_dict(self):
        return {"stuff": self.stuff, "stiff": self.stiff}


class ExampleWithASurprise(Example):
    def __init__(self, surprise, *args):
        Example.__init__(self, *args)
        self.surprise = surprise

    def to_dict(self):
        res = Example.to_dict(self)
        res["surprise"] = self.surprise
        return res

_ = Example("egg", 10)
_ = ExampleWithASurprise("surprising surprise", "bacon", 5)
for e in my_examples:
    print(e.to_dict)
```

The problem is that I want a way to turn an ExampleWithASurprise into a regular Example (once the surprise has been discovered). I could add one method to ExampleWithASuprise:

```
class ExampleWithASurprise(Example):
    def __init__(self, surprise, *args):
        Example.__init__(self, *args)
        self.surprise = surprise

    def to_dict(self):
        res = Example.to_dict(self)
        res["surprise"] = self.surprise
        return res

    def remove_surprise(self):
        my_examples.remove(self)
        _ = Example(self.stuff, self.stiff-10)


ex1 = Example("egg", 10)
ex2 = ExampleWithASurprise("surprising surprise", "bacon", 5)
ex2.remove_surprise()
for e in my_examples:
    print(e.to_dict())
```

The surprise is conveniently removed, which is exactly what I wanted. However this remove_surprise method will quickly become impossible to maintain: in this example the only operation I do is adding 10, which is easily reversed, but the real classes I am interested in have more complex operations than that on their parameters.

What would be the correct way to convert an ExampleWithASurprise into a plain Example so that to_dict works correctly and doesn't list the surprise?

Comment: I would probably add a class method `Example.without_surprise` that takes an `ExampleWithASurprise` and return a new `Example` instance, rather than trying to change the type of an existing object.

Comment: Note that it *is* possible to change the type of an existing object, but doing so won't magically strip any attributes "belonging" to the original class, because instance attributes aren't really tied to any particular class in the first place. (The only link between the two is that instance attributes are often defined by one `__init__` method or another.)

Comment: @chepner I still would have the issue of getting the parameters for Example(), wouldn't I?

Comment: You already have them. The interface to `Example` is public; you just need to extract the correct values from the argument and pass them: `Example(self.stuff, self.more_stuff)`.

Comment: You might notice that means the object will be added to `my_examples` twice, but that's a problem with the original design.

Comment: For *this specific example*, all you need to do is set `self.__class__ = Example`. But that only changes the instance's idea of what type it is: it does nothing to ensure that the newly rechristened object is correctly initialized.

Comment: @chepner except there is no self.more_stuff: I can't extract it (I could in the example because it was simplified, but in reality I can't)

Comment: It is very confusing to rely on `_ = Example(self.stuff, self.stiff-10)` to modify some global list. *That* is a maintenance nighmare.

Comment: Then you are going to have to update your question, because nothing in the code you've shown precludes that.

Comment: " in this example the only operation I do is adding 10, which is easily reversed, but the real classes I am interested in have more complex operations than that on their parameters." yeah, I think you'll want to elaborate on that. I mean, from what you are describing, there doesn't seem to be any way around it.

Comment: But honestly, I would abandon this question unless you can explain *why* you need to change the type, because I suspect you are using the wrong class hierarchy in the first place, and *that's* what you need to fix.

Comment: Please see [XY Problem]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem); I second Chepner's concerns.

Comment: @Prune I think my problem is clear enough: I want my program to behave like with remove_surprise but not to be so hard to maintain.

The real program I work on manages items through various stages of evolution. There are many common properties for all items, including being exportable as dicts, but also specificities that are only relevant for items in certain stages of their evolution.